# Interfacing Assembly with C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm

I am trying to call a assembly function assembled with NASM from a simple C driver class compiled with MinGW GCC.

I am using the following commands to compile and assemble the files.

```
nasm -f win32 asm_main.asm -o asm.o

gcc -c driver.c -o driver.o
```

and the following command to link them together.

```
ld.exe asm.o driver.o -L"C:\Windows\SysWOW64" -lkernel32 -luser32 -o app.exe
```

I get the error message:

```
driver.o:driver.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `__main'
```

Here is my sample assembly and C code

```
; asm.asm
extern _MessageBoxA, _ExitProcess

section .data
    title db "Greeting", 0
    message db "Hello World!", 0
section .bss

section .text
    global _asm_main

_asm_main:
    enter 0, 0

    push dword 0 
    push dword title
    push dword message 
    push dword 0 
    call _MessageBoxA

    push dword 0 
    call _ExitProcess

    mov eax, 0 
    leave
    ret
```

```
// driver.c
extern int asm_main();


void main()
{   
    asm_main(); 
}
```

Any thought why I might get this error?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I got my problem solved by changing ExitProcess to _ExitProcess@4 and MessageBox to _MessageBoxA@16 and linking with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the gcc C startup routine `__main` (called by `main` when you compile with gcc), which is usually defined in libgcc.  The easiest way to get it is to link with gcc (which includes it) rather than ld.  Alternately, add `-lgcc` to the link command line.

Comment: I tried gcc and got a different set of errors: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(tlsthrd.o):(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection@4' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingwex.a(misc.o):(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection@4'

Comment: @Ian, you need then to add linking to win32 or something. Try adding `-lwin32`. If that doesn't work, it's a hint at least! You are missing some fundamental windows library.